# Showing a location with respect to another location without using Map

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, location

I am creating a location based iPhone App.

I have two locations (their lat and long).

One location is fixed to center of the UIView, How can show the other location with respect to first location.

Please give me code if available.

Comment: Mapping is a complex problem. Mapping maps a location on the surface of a sphere onto a flat plane, which distorts the things that are mapped. The map kit uses Mercator projection, which is one of the more commonly used map projections. For locations of a few 10s of kilometers you can ignore the curvature of the earth and simply convert lat/long values to rectangular coordinates. However, the distance between points of longitude change based on the latitude, so you should at least calculate the number of kilometers/degree of latitude for your current longitude.

Comment: What are you trying to show? Are you trying to draw a simple map of the user's surroundings, or just show the second location's position relative to the fist at some arbitrary scale?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to find the distance between your two points then you could use the CoreLocation function:

```
CLLocation *startLocation =  [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:startLatitude longitude:startLongitude];
CLLocation *endLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:endLatitude longitude:endLongitude];

CLLocationDistance distanceMeters = [startLocation distanceFromLocation:endLocation];
```